# Signed integer convertion

Tags: binary

What is -10234(10) in binary with a fixed width of 16 bits in 1) one's complement 2) two's complement 3) signed magnitude.

Please help me step by step, I feel confused about the above three. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a homework problem.  I'm not going to do your homework for you, because the goal is for you to learn, but I can explain the stuff in my own words for you.  In my experience, most of the people who get lost on this stuff just need to hear things said in a way that works for them, rather than having the same thing repeated.

The first thing that you need to understand for this is what the positive of that number is in base 2.  Since the problem said you have 16 bits to handle the signed version in, you'll only have 15 bits to get this done.

As far as how to make it negative...

When you're doing signed magnitude, you would have one of those bits signal whether it was positive or negative.  For an example, I'll do 4 bits of signed magnitude.  Our number starts off as 3, that is 0011.  The signed bit is always the most significant bit, so -3 would be 1011.

When you're doing one's complement, you just flip all of the bits.  (So if you had an 8 bit one's complement number that's currently positive - let's say it's 25(9+1) or 00011001(1+1), to make that 25 in one's complement, you'd flip all of those bits, so -25(9+1) is 11100110(1+1) in one's complement.

Two's complement is the same sort of thing, except that rather than having all 1s (11111111(1+1) for the 8 bit version be -0, a number we rarely care to distinguish from +0, it adjusts all of the negative numbers by one so that's now -1.

Note that I'm giving the bases in the form of number +1, because *every* base is base 10 in that base.  But that's me, a grizzled computer professional; if you're still in school, represent bases the way your instructor tells you to, but understand they're crazy.  (I can prove they're crazy: 1. They're human.  2. QED.  In future years when some people are just learning from AIs, the proof is slightly more complicated.  1. They were made, directly or indirectly by humans.  2  All humans are crazy.  3. QED.)

Comment: In my case, firstly I convert the decimal to binary; 10234 = 10011111111010. And in one's complement, it is 01100000000101. In two's complement, it is 01100000000110. In signed magnitude, -10234 would be 10011111111010. Am I right for those three.

Comment: All of your answers are just 14 bits, so that's not 16 bits.